# Properly getting the output when word does not exist in a list and a list of tuples also when a word already exists in a tuple list

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I am making a code about lists and tuples. But I can't figure out how to make the code properly print if the word is missing in the the list. (It keeps printing out the entire length of the list and fills it with word does not exist)

Like the list has 3 words and 3 descriptions in it and when looking up a word that is not in the list the output becomes

"word does not exist"

"word does not exist"

"word does not exist"

And it's only meant to print out the text once.

```
def upkollning(lista):
   print ', '.join(lista[0])
   ord_val = raw_input("What word do you wanna look up?: ")
   for x in range(0, len(lista[0])):
       if lista[0][x] == ord_val:
           print lista[1][x],"\n"               
       else:
            if ord_val not in lista[0]:
                print "word does not exist"
```

Second issue I can't figure out how to get the "word already exists" to appear when adding an already existing word. It just skips the whole thing and just keeps putting the already existing word into the tuple list.

```
def tuplist():
tuplist = [("pancakes","something for breakfast")]
return tuplist
def instoppning2tup(tuplelista):
   word = raw_input("Type the word: ")
   #desc = raw_input("Type the description: ")
   if word in tuplelista:
      print "word already exists"

   else:
        desc = raw_input("Give descrption to the word: ")
        tuplelista.append( (word,desc) )

   return tuplelista
```

And third same problem as the first problem I get the "Word doesn't exist" for every single for every single ''word'' the tuple list contains.

```
def upkollning2tup(tuplelista):
   for x in range(0, len(tuplelista)):
           print tuplelista[x][0],    
   ord_val = raw_input("\nWhat word do you wanna look up?: ")
   for x in range(0, len(tuplelista)):
       if tuplelista[x][0] == ord_val:
           print tuplelista[x][1],"\n"
       else:
           print "Word doesn't exist"
```

So does anyone here feel generous to help out?

Comment: You should ask each of your three questions separately, since each uses different code. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you want a lookup table. So instead of a list of tuples you should use a dictionary. But to answer your questions:

1) see answer to question 3

2)
`word` is never in tuplelista because word is a string and never equivalent to a tuple in the list. Instead use `if word in list(zip(*tuplelista))[0]`

3) rather do

```
def upkollning2tup(tuplelista):
    #for x in range(0, len(tuplelista)):
    #    print tuplelista[x][0],    
    ord_val = raw_input("\nWhat word do you wanna look up?: ")
    if ord_val in list(zip(*tuplelista))[0]:
        print "Word doesn't exist"
    else:
        for elem in tuplelista:
            if elem[0] == ord_val:
                print elem[1]
```